# How to fix Vulnerable WebRTC version error by third party libraries?

Tags: android, twilio, webrtc

My Application in play developer console is showing error "Vulnerable WebRTC Versions, Your app uses a bad version of WebRTC, which contains security vulnerabilities."

I am using twilio video SDK, however it seems to be the latest version. Still cant figure out which library is using webrtc.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.38'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'


debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.5.2"
releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2"
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.1'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.5.0"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.38'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.38'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-beta01"

//nav components
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'

implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'

implementation 'com.github.aabhasr1:OtpView:v1.1.2'
implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:2.2.6'

implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:7.5.1'
implementation "com.twilio:audioswitch:1.1.2"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0"

//progress bar
implementation 'com.github.uzairiqbal91:CircularTimerView:1.0'
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"

//country code picker
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.6.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'io.github.informramiz:nameinitialscircleimageview:1.6'
implementation 'com.github.Drjacky:ImagePicker:2.1.16'

//App update
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.1'

//Live
implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:2.2.7'

implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
```

Is there a way to find which of these libraries use webrtc and what versions?

Comment: Run a Gradle dependency report to see your whole tree of dependencies, including transitive ones.

Comment: see https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/731